# How to use strspn to find the number of characters other than those mentioned in arg 2 of strspn?

Tags: c, string

How do I count the number of values other than the ones mentioned in the `strspn` function? I know `strspn` counts the total number of appearances of the characters mentioned in its argument 2, but I want to do the opposite of it.

For example if I have the string:  `ABCDEFGH`

I want to count the number of characters other than `D`. So the answer would be: `7`.

Is there anyway I could do this with `strspn`?

Comment: `strspn(str, set)` is not doing exactly what you think. It returns the length of the longest prefix of `str` with all characters being in `set`, not the entire count.

Comment: Detail: string `"ABCDEFGH"`  consists of _9_ `char`. So the goal appears to be "count the number of characters other than `'D'` and `'\0'`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute the *total* number of characters that do not match the set, you need to implement this function yourself, with a loop:

```
size_t count_non_matching_chars(const char *str, const char *set) {
    size_t pos = 0, count = 0, chunk;

    while (str[pos] != '\0') {
        pos += strspn(str + pos, set);  /* skip the matching chars */
        chunk = strcspn(str + pos, set); /* count non matching chars */
        pos += chunk;
        count += chunk;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is an alternative that uses only `strspn()` and is slightly less efficient if there are many non matching characters:

```
size_t count_non_matching_chars(const char *str, const char *set) {
    size_t pos = 0, count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        pos += strspn(str + pos, set);  /* skip the matching chars */
        if (str[pos] == '\0')
            break;
        count++;  /* count and skip the non-matching character */
        pos++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Nice code as OP requested "do this with strspn" +1.

Answer (score -3):

Try subtracting the results from strspn from the total length of the string:

```
strlen(string) - strspn(string);
```

Comment: Not really, this computes the number of characters from the first that does not match until the end of string.  Furthermore, incorrect syntax for `strspn`

Comment: @DBug Yeah, unfortunately this answer simply isn't correct.  Perhaps it would be the best to delete it, because I don't see a way to make it correct.